# __init__.py import default classes

Tags: python

Say I have ClassA, ClassB and ClassC each within their own .py files called `ClassA.py`, `ClassB.py` and `ClassC.py` respectively.

```
# Inside ClassA.py
class ClassA:
    pass
```

In my `__init__.py` I end up with

```
from .ClassA import ClassA
from .ClassB import ClassB
from .ClassC import ClassC
```

Every time I add a new class (using the same structure), I have to change the `__init__.py`. Is there a recommended way to automate this, given that all files in this package follow the same (not-quite-pythonic-but-oh-well) structure?

Comment: Putting each class in a `ClassName.py` file is a bad idea in Python. At least name it `classname.py` instead of `ClassName.py`, if you're determined to go with a one-class-per-file structure. Naming a class and a module the same thing is a recipe for weird import-order-dependent problems, where sometimes you get the class and sometimes you get the module.

Comment: Hmmm...I'm not sure what to make of this comment.  I use this structure all the time, and I've never had any problems.  I have `from com.mycompany.Foo import Foo` calls all over the place.  Maybe it's the full qualification of the class's name, including its package, that keeps me out of trouble.  I do think I've run into this pattern quite a bit in other packages, but again, maybe not when imported this way...with a relative import.  So I'm not saying you're wrong.  I just haven't hit this in many years of Python coding.

Comment: I also can't see in just looking at this how it would be a problem.  In `from X import Y`, isn't X always a package name and Y always a symbol name?  I can't think where the two would ever be ambiguous.

Comment: @Steve: `from com.mycompany.Foo import Foo` is safe enough, but look at how the code in the question does `from .ClassA import ClassA` in `__init__.py`. The entire purpose of this is to make `from package import ClassA` import the class, but depending on import order, it may either import the class or the module.

Comment: There are a number of other problems this kind of writing-Java-in-Python style causes. For example, it increases circular import problems. If two classes in the same file depend on each other, execution order is straightforward. If you're putting every class in its own file, you end up needing a circular import, with all the associated initialization order problems.

Comment: Ah!  Nice example.  I was hoping you'd do that, because I assumed you did know what you were talking about.  btw, when I did this (I had to look back), it was for a fully dynamic need...a Chef-like system where users could drop in new .py files to describe new packages.  We used lowercase package/file names, and the classes inside were always a Package object, so our case was nothing like this.  Glad you came a long to shed light on this particular use case.

Answer (score 3):

It is *possible*, but not recommended.

Consider the following directory structure:

```
├── test_module
│   ├── ClassA.py
│   ├── ClassB.py
│   └── __init__.py
```

We want to import `ClassA.ClassA` and `ClassB.ClassB` into `__init__.py` programmatically.

Assume these are the contents of `ClassA.py`:

```
class ClassA:
    pass
```

`ClassB.py` is identical, save for the name of the `class`.

Now, say that in `__init__.py` we want to traverse the root directory non-recursively (not that it matters, since we have no directories) and import all `classes` from all modules within.

`__init__.py`:

```
import os
from importlib import import_module

my_location = os.path.dirname(__file__)
module_list = [file
               for file in os.listdir(my_location)
               if os.path.splitext(file)[1] == '.py'
               and file != '__init__.py']
modules = [import_module(f'.{os.path.splitext(module)[0]}', __name__)
           for module in module_list]
```

After running `import test_module`, the `classes` from `ClassA.py` and `ClassB.py` will be imported into the working namespace as `test_module.ClassA.ClassA` and `test_module.ClassB.ClassB` respectively.

To illustrate:

```
>>> import test_module
>>> test_module.ClassA.ClassA()
<test_module.ClassA.ClassA object at 0x7f1e66181fd0>
```

For completeness, if you want this script to mimic the behaviour of `from X import Y`:

```
globals().update({name: getattr(module, name)
                  for module in modules
                  for name in module.__dict__
                  if not name.startswith('_')})
```

Importing:

```
>>> import test_module
>>> test_module.ClassA()
<test_module.ClassA.ClassA object at 0x7fb8edb9dfd0>
```

These will make those names accessible as `test_module.ClassA` etc. (because you are importing *from* `test_module`, we add an additional layer of indirection. In `test_module`'s scope, they are accessible directly as unqualified name.

There are additional bells and whistles we could add, such as checking each module's `__all__` attribute and performing recursive traversal of sub-directories, but that is rather out of scope of this question, and I must emphasise that to my mind, it would be better to *refactor your code such that this is not needed in the first place*, rather than tack on functionality that plays with the internals of Python where it does not seem to be **essential**.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.  This is what the [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) package is for.  It contains the lower level calls that actually do the importing.  It lets you do imports by calling the methods it provides.

So you could use Python `os.path.listdir` or whatever to learn what your subpackages are, and then make calls to `importlib` to import each of them.

I haven't done much of this myself.  Just enough to know this exists.  Maybe someone else can give you more details.  Also, this link might be helpful to you:

https://dev.to/0xcrypto/dynamic-importing-stuff-in-python--1805

Comment: Per both the comments and the other answer, I'll just point out for readers that I didn't say "should"...just "could".  My use case...why I knew about `importlib`...was very different.  There was no potential for name clash there and it was a completely different use case.  **This begs the question...what IS the right way to do this in this particular use case?**.  Seems like a valid thing to want to do.

Comment: I would say that the right thing to do is to refactor your code so you don't need to do this in the first place. To be honest, this seems more like Java than Python, as another user said. (because personally, I can't come up with a situation where I would *need* to do this)

Comment: I agree completely if we're taking about the same coder or team being responsible for the outer module and the inner classes.  If it's just to save writing a line of code in \__init__.py for each of 5-10 classes that might come along, it isn't worth it, IMO.  If this is more of an extensible platform thing, where other coders might want to just drop in "extension functions", then I could see using something like this.  But in that case, I figure you'd want those extensions to live outside the primary module anyway.  So I also can't think of a clear reason to add this complexity.

Comment: Sorry, I had to take down my dev.to account and the blog. So the link in answer will result in a 404. Reposted article on my new blog https://hackberry.xyz/dynamic-importing-stuff-in-python